# Trying to fake a Strong Named Assembly, but "manifest definition does not match"

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain, .net-assembly, interception

I'd like to intercept the communication between a plug-in and a host assembly.

I've tried to load `ThirdPartyPlugin.dll` into an [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) sandbox (code below), to intercept its attempts at loading of `HostLibrary.dll` assembly (I'm using trick with handling the [AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event). Instead of the original `HostLibrary.dll`, I'm then trying to inject a fake one, with some different functionalities.

Unfortunately, the original `HostLibrary.dll` is a *Strong Named Assembly*, and I think because of that I'm getting an **exception like below** in my program:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'HostLibrary, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1a2b3c4d5e6f7890' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

The fake assembly I created does match the name (`"HostLibrary"`), and the version (`"7.0.0.0"`) of the original assembly; at one time I think I even made it apparently match the `PublicKeyToken` (when I printed [Assembly.FullName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.fullname.aspx), it was identical), but the exception still occurs.

**Do you have any ideas as to how I could resolve this problem?** Is it possible to resolve at all? Does it happen because of digital signature, or something else? If signature, then is it possible to disable the check? Actually, from reading [an article by Ian Picknell](http://ianpicknell.blogspot.com/2010/02/tampering-with-strong-named-assembly.html), I'd think I should not really be having this problem... so what's wrong?

The code is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
    setup.ApplicationName = "WrapperBuddy";
    setup.ApplicationBase = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;

    AppDomain sandbox = AppDomain.CreateDomain("SandboxBuddy", null, setup);
    sandbox.AssemblyResolve += delegate(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        String name = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name;
        return BuildFakeAssembly(name);
    };

    sandbox.DoCallBack(delegate()
    {
        Assembly plugin = LoadAssembly(PLUGIN_DIR, "ThirdPartyPlugin");
        System.Console.WriteLine(plugin.GetExportedTypes());   // (1)
    });
}
```

with helper functions defined as:

```
static Assembly LoadAssembly(String dir, String name)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(dir, name) + ".dll";
    return Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
}

static Assembly BuildFakeAssembly(String name)
{
    AssemblyName aName = new AssemblyName(name);
    // see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w58ww7se%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w58ww7se%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
    aName.KeyPair = new StrongNameKeyPair(new FileStream(@"MyKey.snk", FileMode.Open));
                                  // MyKey.snk is a random key generated using sn.exe
    aName.Version = new Version("7.0.0.0");
    //aName.SetPublicKeyToken(new byte[] { 0x11, 0x22, ... }); // didn't help 

    AssemblyBuilder ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
        aName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);

    ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(aName.Name, aName.Name + ".dll");
    return ab;
}
```

I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: Why the -1 vote?? Please, do comment if you have some critique...

Comment: If the assembly is signed, I don't think you're *supposed* to be able to make a fake version.

Comment: This is exactly the type of thing strong naming is designed to prevent.

Comment: How do you set the AppDomainSetup object that you pass to AppDomain.CreateDomain?

Comment: @PanosRontogiannis: uh, I deleted it accidentally when cleaning up the code for posting. I've now added it back, thanks for noticing.

Comment: @akavel The reason I asked you is that the bypassTrustedAppStrongNames element is working only on full-trust AppDomains and the AppDomainSetup can be used to specify the evidence and policy for the application domain. In your case, you do not set it which means that it will use the same evidence with your main AppDomain. Is your main AppDomain running in full-trust?

Comment: @bmm6o: but I found some indications hinting that it might be possible to workaround this (see e.g. [Ian Picknell's blog](http://ianpicknell.blogspot.com/2010/02/tampering-with-strong-named-assembly.html)), and I'm in need for that. Also, when using a controlled AppDomain sandbox, I'd suspect it should be possible to disable security features.

Comment: @PanosRontogiannis: Actually, I have my codebase sprinkled with lots of WriteLine(sandbox.IsFullTrust) and likes, and they all seem to return True, so I think this part is ok? (I decided to remove it here, and some other things too, to reduce code somewhat, otherwise I was afraid noone would want read this question at all :/ ). That said, thanks for your help till now. By the way, I found some suggestions over the 'net to use a *fuslogvw.exe* tool, but Windows SDK fails to install on my machine, sigh...

Comment: @akavel You don't have to install Windows SDK in order to use the Fusion Log Viewer. Just copy it. Read this blog entry for more info on how to enable it http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx.